# onChange event---> only alert working?!! other functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="col-md-2"><select id="DDlUser" onchange="LoadCheckboxesForUser()"   class="form-control" style="width:100%;" >


 function LoadCheckboxesForUser() {

    alert("hi");
    $("#checkbox1").attr("checked", "checked");
}
```

only alert is working, it does not make checkbox checked,

otherwise when i use this function on $(document).ready , it works fine

Comment: _"it does not make checkbox checked"_ ? Where are they ?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok it was masterpage issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.prop` method to `check` the `checkbox`

```
$("#checkbox1").prop("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: Use `.prop` ? Why ? Why `.attr` will fail ?

Comment: it was masterpage issue